# ABAddressbook notification of delete of Record

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I use the kABpersonModificationDateProperty to detect AddressBook records that have been added/modified since the last startup.

Is it possible to detect which records have been deleted since my last startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dearly wish it were so.

Your only option here is to cache all the record IDs, and then compare the full list at startup.

You're still exposed to situations where iOS rewrites all the IDs (such as when syncing via iCloud), in which case it will appear that all the records were deleted and an entirely new batch added. You can try to recognize cases where the ID was changed on an existing record by comparing fields (such as first/last name).